# Python: fastest way to match keys and values between two dicts

Tags: python

Besides iterating each dict and matching, are there any ways to accomplish this?
Mainly asking this question to see if there are some efficient way of doing this instead of looping through. Maybe there are some func in itertools module that can do this or not that I am not aware of? sort of like zip? izip?

dict1:

```
{'command': ('aks',), 'variants': ('common',), 'name': 'oop', 'imports': ('abc', 'efg')}
```

dict2:

```
{'exports': <type 'dict'>, 'serialize': <type 'bool'>, 'force': <type 'bool'>, 'name': <type 'str'>, 'build_host': <type 'str'>, 'imports': <type 'list'>, 'logfile_timeout': <type 'int'>, 'update': 'skip_check', 'by_variant': <type 'list'>, 'command': <type 'list'>, 'signature': <type 'str'>, 'variants': 'skip_check'}
```

desired outcome:
enumerated or dict of values of same key in both dict together

```
commands:
(('aks',), <type 'list'>)
variants:
(('common',), 'skip_check')
name:
('oop', <type 'str'>)
imports:
(('abc', 'efg'),<type 'list'>)
```

Comment: Is `commands` supposed to appear anywhere in the second dict?

Comment: @user2357112 yeah its the 10th one

Comment: @user2357112 typo. its suppposed to be command in first dict. ill fix it

Comment: @user2357112 'by_variant': <type 'list'>, 'command': <type 'list'>, 'signature': <type 'str'>,

Comment: How's that, does that do it?

Comment: @AaronHall that def does it. wonder if there is a one liner that can do it or even more simpler way. but yes. def better than what I had.

Comment: You say command in your dict keys, but it's commands in your expected output. I refined my answer just a bit.

Comment: What did you want for your final output? A single unified dict with a list of the values?

Comment: @AaronHall I have not made that mind yet. I just want the two values of the same key in each dict to be grouped. and whatever that are grouped could be represented a list or in a dict keyed with the same original key of the values grouped.... as long as those two values are grouped in an efficient manner, i would be fine.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50089/discussion-between-aaron-hall-and-ealeon)

Comment: I'm pretty sure I gave you this: > dict of values of same key in both dict together

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what exactly you are looking for, but this is the best I could do:

```
keys = d1.viewkeys() & d2
print zip(map(d1.get, keys), map(d2.get, keys))
```

**Output**

```
[(('abc', 'efg'), <type 'list'>),
 (('common',), 'skip_check'),
 (('aks',), <type 'list'>),
 ('oop', <type 'str'>)]
```

**Note:** This assumes that the keys in `d1` are all present in `d2`.

Comment: I like this! i am very tempted to accept this as the answer.

Comment: viewkeys() comes with which python version?

Comment: @ealeon: 2.7. If you don't have that, `set(d1) & set(d2)` works.

Comment: Downvoter, please let me know what is wrong with this answer.

Answer (score 2):

This solution works for most versions of Python, whereas `dict.viewkeys` only works in Python 2.7 (not 2.6, nor 3, which you would have to substitute `dict.keys`):

```
dict1 = {'command': ('aks',), 'variants': ('common',), 'name': 'oop', 'imports': ('abc', 'efg')}
dict2 =  {'exports': dict, 'serialize': bool, 'force': bool, 'name': str, 'build_host': str, 'imports': list, 'logfile_timeout': int, 'update': 'skip_check', 'by_variant': list, 'command': list, 'signature': str, 'variants': 'skip_check'}
for key in set(dict1).intersection(dict2):
    print(key + ':')
    print(dict1[key], dict2[key])
```

prints:

```
imports:
(('abc', 'efg'), <type 'list'>)
variants:
(('common',), 'skip_check')
command:
(('aks',), <type 'list'>)
name:
('oop', <type 'str'>)
```

What you probably want is to group the intersection of the keys in a dict:

```
intersect_dict= dict((key, [d[key] for d in (dict1, dict2)]) 
                                   for key in set(dict1).intersection(dict2))

import pprint
pprint.pprint(intersect_dict)
```

prints:

```
{'command': [('aks',), <type 'list'>],
 'imports': [('abc', 'efg'), <type 'list'>],
 'name': ['oop', <type 'str'>],
 'variants': [('common',), 'skip_check']}
```